# Any way to speed up functional programming with Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate Rcpp into R effectively, and as my test case I chose the Bisection Method, a popular method of root finding.  It also requires a tiny bit of functional programming, since you need to call the function you're finding the root of in order to find the root.  It could be I'm wrong and I just don't speak good C++/Rcpp.

The problem is that the Rcpp function actually takes (much) longer to run, I'm pretty sure since the function is dealing with the R function every time it is called.  I've provided some benchmarks below, and the code of my R and C++ versions of the code:

```
 microbenchmark::microbenchmark(bisectionMethod(function(x) x^3, -10, 7),
 bisectionMethodCPP(function(x) x^3, -10, 7), 
 uniroot(function(x) x^3, c(-10, 7)))

> Unit: microseconds
>                                     expr      min       lq      mean   median
> bisectionMethod(function(x) x^3, -10, 7)   54.521   55.904   69.9303   58.005
> bisectionMethodCPP(function(x) x^3, -10, 7) 1463.781 1496.900 1677.2274 1532.158
>     uniroot(function(x) x^3, c(-10, 7))   62.016   65.862  103.2841   72.320
>    uq      max neval cld
> 62.0835 1100.376   100  a 
> 1604.4215 4941.922   100   b
> 98.5615 2135.752   100  a
```

Rcpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector bisectionMethodCPP(Function f, NumericVector a, NumericVector b, 
                          NumericVector eps = 0.0000000001)
{
  if (is_true(all(b <= a))) {
    NumericVector switchVal = a;
    a = b;
    b = switchVal;
  }
  NumericVector fa = f(a);
  NumericVector fb = f(b);
  if (is_true(all(fa*fb > 0))) {
    return -999.0;
  }
  while (is_true(all((b-a) > eps))) {
    NumericVector middle = ((b+a)/2.0);
    NumericVector fmid = f(middle);
    if (is_true(all(fmid*fb > 0))) {
      b = middle;
    }
    else if (is_true(all(fmid*fa > 0))) {
      a = middle;
    }
    else if (is_true(all(fmid == 0.0))) {
      return middle;
    }
    fa = f(a);
    fb = f(b);
  }
  NumericVector Ans = ((b+a)/2.0);
  return Ans;
}
```

R version:

```
bisectionMethod <- function(f, a, b, eps = 1e-10, iter.max = 100) {
  ## R version of the Bisection Method
  if (f(a)*f(b) > 0) {
    stop("Bisection method invalid for this kind of case.")
  }
  if (b <= a) {
    switchVal = a
    a = b
    b = switchVal
  }
  i <- 1
  while ((b-a) > eps) {
    middle = (b+a)/2.0
    if (f(middle) * f(b) > 0) {
      b = middle
    }
    else if (f(middle) * f(a) > 0) {
      a = middle
   }
   else if (f(middle) == 0.0) {
     return(middle)
   }
   i <- i+1
   if (iter.max == i) {
     stop("Maximum iterations reached without locating root.")
   }
 }
 return ((b+a)/2.0)
}
```

Comment: You are paying the price of interfacing an R function from C++ code on each iteration.  Not a good design.

Comment: William Bell, I don't think you're going to get much more of a direct (albeit not-good-news) comment or answer from somebody. (Dirk is the main author of Rcpp and knows a thing or two.) There have been several other questions along the years (here on SO, elsewhere) asking similar questions, and in the end any scenario that calls an R function from an Rcpp function is going to lose some/much of the performance improvements of Rcpp. There is no getting around it when you think you need the flexibility of passing arbitrary R functions. Good luck.

Comment: @r2evans you seem to suggest there's a way around it when you need less flexibility.  Would you care to explain?

Comment: Yes, don't try to support "arbitrary" (R) functions, instead write what functionality you need in Rcpp. If you think you'll have one of (say) five functions you would likely use, code them in Rcpp and pass some unambiguous name in place of the R function. Something like `bisectionMethodCPP("myRcppCube", -10, 7)`, and your `bisectionMethodCPP` function chooses its companion function based on that string. (Passing anything "static"-ish is good enough, so integers work, too.)

Comment: @r2evans This is going a little off topic, but do you happen to know how to make function factories in C++?  Googling isn't helping me.

Comment: Not my specialty, sorry that I cannot be of more assistance there. Your example shows a cube-function, if it is likely that most of your candidate functions will always be some parametric (powers of 0 through (say) 3), then one "hack" could be to add arguments for each of the coefficients, say `NumericVector bisectionMethodCPP(exp0, exp1, exp2, exp3, a, b, eps)`, where the cube example would be `bisectionMethodCPP(0, 0, 0, 1, a, b, eps)`. But this is a hack, somewhat self-limiting, and perhaps not best.

Comment: You could stay flexible by letting the user pass in a C++ function as an Xptr, e.g. http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers-rcppxptrutils/